# Directly rename legend in word, when data is not available

Tags: plot, ms-word, legend

I have a scatter plot now in microsoft word. It seems this plot was created in excel and copied into word keeping source formatting. The legend in the plot is incorrectly labelled which looks unprofessional.

Normally I would go to select data and rename the series, but because of how I received the plot I do not have access to the underlying data and it will not allow this option.

Is there any way to directly edit the text in this legend entry while keeping the correct color coding etc.

I have tried numerous right clicking and any format options I have been able to find to no avail. I feel there should be a way to do this simple task, but it is far from obvious. I am using windows version Microsoft word 2013, if that is important.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you can't access the underyling chart then it was probably copied and pasted from Excel as a picture. So the only way you can change anything is to edit the picture, for example positioning text boxes with the changed text over the chart.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It is a directly input chart so I can separately edit all of the chart elements, except for the legend. I guess I will manually add a text box and group the items, as this seems to be the only option.

Comment: Which command was used to create the chart? This sounds very strange to me... But it also looks like an end-user question, at this point, so should be on Super User, not StackOverflow?

Comment: I am guessing it was created by copying from excel and pasting in source format into word. Sorry if this was in the wrong forum, I have changed it with a text box. thank you for the help.